# Trying to compare old v new value after the string update

Tags: rust

I am learning rust borrow checker and struggling with this:

I want to compare the old value and the new value after the string has been cleared

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut s  = String::from("first_word second_word");
    let idx = first_word_index(&mut s);

    let first_word = &mut s[0..idx]; 

    println!("Before clearing the original string: {}", first_word);

    // I get error here: 
    s.clear();
    
    println!("After clearing the original string: {}", first_word);
}

fn first_word_index(s: &mut String) -> usize  {
    let bytes = s.as_bytes();
    for (i, &item) in bytes.iter().enumerate() {
        if item == b' ' {
            return i
        }
    }
    s.len()
}
```

The errors says:

```
cannot borrow `s` as mutable more than once at a time
second mutable borrow occurs here
```

I do not want to clone the string, because I want to see the actual value of the string both before and after it has been cleared;

Comment: You can't expect such behaviour to work in any language let alone rust.  You are basically clearing the memory and trying to read it post that which is wrong. Best part is rust catches this at compile time for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The borrow checker is saving you from undefined behavior.  Other languages would happily compile code like this, but reading *anything* from `first_word` after `s.clear()` could cause a crash or other misbehavior from the program.

`first_word` borrows from `s`.  It contains a pointer to the start of the slice (the beginning of the string data, in this case), and a length (whatever is stored in `idx`).

After you clear `s`, `first_word` would no longer refer to a valid region of `s` -- the string has been cleared, so the length of 10 would cover a memory region that may not be owned by the `String` value anymore.

Rust knows this, and it doesn't allow you to use `first_word` after you clear the string, because `s.clear()` requires an *exclusive* (mutable) borrow of `s`.  An exclusive borrow cannot exist concurrently with any other borrow, so the borrow by `first_word` must end -- but you try to use it later, which is a violation of Rust's borrowing rules.

You can't do this because Rust doesn't let you do it.  It's not something to be worked around; it's disallowed, period.

If you just want to inspect the string itself after clearing it, print out `s` instead of `first_word`:

```
println!("After clearing the original string: {}", s);
```